# communication solution between azure app service and external program

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I am building a website using ASP.NET MVC which gonna be deployed as Azure app service and I got another program which will interact with the website backend in real time and sends live data which needs to be displayed on the website as live data and it is bi-directional. We used message queues (Azure service bus) before and these doesn't seem to be reliable (delays coming up on sending and receiving data).

Can anyone suggest me what is the best way to go with?

Websockets or database operations or anything else

Comment: Azure Service Bus is pretty reliable, I'm curious to understand in more detail what reliability issues you have had.  It might be worth posting the code that you've been using to send/receive messages.  Note that as it stands, your question would elicit opinion-based answers...

Comment: Thanks for your comment Brendon, the data we are passing is pretty bidirectional, so website user can send data to external program and vice versa. Message queues are causing delays if there are 1000 of unit connection going on.